# Tkinter wont display variables correctly

Tags: python, tkinter, calculator

I'm new to Tkinter and I'm simply trying to make a GUI for my multiplicity calculator. When I tell it to print the multiplicity it gives me a seemingly random string of numbers. Any help?

```
import sys
import tkinter
from tkinter import *

def Start():
    numberOneList = []
    numberTwoList = []
    multiples = 10000
    iterations = 0

    multiplicity = int(entry3.get())
    numberOne = int(entry1.get())
    numberTwo = int(entry2.get())

    for i in range(multiples):
        mNumberOne = numberOne * i
        numberOneList.append(mNumberOne)
        mNumberTwo = numberTwo * i
        numberTwoList.append(mNumberTwo)
    text1.insert(INSERT, "\n")
    text1.insert(INSERT, "Common multiplicities:")
    text1.insert(INSERT, "\n")
    text1.insert(INSERT, "Calculating...")
    text1.insert(INSERT, "\n")
    for i in numberOneList:
        for a in numberTwoList:
            if a == i:
                if a != 0:
                    text1.insert(INSERT, int(entry1.get()), "x", i / int(entry1.get()), "=", i)
                    text1.insert(INSERT, int(entry2.get()), "x", a / int(entry2.get()), "=", a)
                    text1.insert(INSERT, "\n")
                    iterations += 1
                    if iterations == multiplicity:
                        sys.exit()
                    else:
                        continue
                else:
                    continue
            else:
                continue

master = tkinter.Tk()
master.title("Multiplicity Calculator")

text1 = Text(master)
text1.pack(side = BOTTOM)

label1 = Label(master, text = "Number 1: ")
label1.pack(side = LEFT)

entry1 = Entry(master, bd = 5, textvariable = IntVar())
entry1.pack(side = LEFT)

label2 = Label(master, text = "Number 2: ")
label2.pack(side = LEFT)

entry2 = Entry(master, bd = 5, textvariable = IntVar())
entry2.pack(side = LEFT)

label3 = Label(master, text = "Number of Multiplicities")
label3.pack(side = LEFT)

entry3 = Entry(master, bd = 5, textvariable = IntVar())
entry3.pack(side = LEFT)

button1 = Button(master, text = "Calculate", width = 8, command = Start)
button1.pack()



master.mainloop()
```

The issue is in lines

```
text1.insert(INSERT, int(entry1.get()), "x", i / int(entry1.get()), "=", i)
text1.insert(INSERT, int(entry2.get()), "x", a / int(entry2.get()), "=", a)
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using comma, concatenate it all into one argument.

```
text1.insert(INSERT, str(int(entry1.get())) + "x" + str(i / int(entry1.get())) + "=" + str(i))
```

> You can use an optional third argument to the insert method to attach
>   one or more tags to the newly inserted text

```
text.insert(INSERT, "link", ("a", "href"+href))
```